# How to includes support for using the svg with jsdom node package

Tags: node.js, svg, jsdom

Consider the below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="" type="text/css"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg>
    <g id='test'>
        <polygon points="942.028,-1134.35 787.67,-1134.35 787.67,-1022.34 942.028,-1022.34 942.028,-1134.35"/>
        <text text-anchor="middle" x="864.849" y="-1101.18">Test</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Following is the node.js code to which parses it:

```
var strSVG = /* SAME AS ABOVE */  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>    <?xml-stylesheet href="" type="text/css"?>    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">    <svg>        <g id="test">            <polygon points="942.028,-1134.35 787.67,-1134.35 787.67,-1022.34 942.028,-1022.34 942.028,-1134.35"/>            <text text-anchor="middle" x="864.849" y="-1101.18">Test</text>        </g>    </svg>';
var strYourText = 'Hello';
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
jsdom.env({
        html : strSVG, 
        done : function (errors, window) { 
            console.log(window.document.getElementById("test").innerHTML); 
            //doing some other stuff here and ultimately writing to a file.
        }
    }
);
```

**Issue**: [jsdom](http://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) will move the `<text>` tag inside the `<polygon>` tag. i.e. output is as follows:

```
<polygon points="942.028,-1134.35 787.67,-1134.35 787.67,-1022.34 942.028,-1022.34 942.028,-1134.35">            
     <text text-anchor="middle" x="864.849" y="-1101.18">
          Test
     </text>       
</polygon>
```

But it has to be in the other format which is as follows:

```
<polygon points="942.028,-1134.35 787.67,-1134.35 787.67,-1022.34 942.028,-1022.34 942.028,-1134.35"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="864.849" y="-1101.18">Test</text>
```

Could any one help?